# Linux/Bash: Comment every line matching a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, c

`sed` is foreign to me, to say the least. I'd like to traverse a C project tree and comment out every line calling the function `LogMsg()`. Something that'd achieve the following:

```
foreach: line within *.c
  if: line contains "LogMsg"
    prepend "//"
```

Or so. Also, then, I'd like to see if I could achieve the reverse, though I imagine that might be more difficult.

I feel like `sed` is the right tool for this job, but I'm no expert in batch text file edits. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command to use is:

```
 sed '/LogMsg/ s?^?//?' filename  new_filename
```

It locates the lines, in the file *filename*, containing *LogMsg*, and substitutes at the beginning of the line (*^*), the double slash. The question mark is used as a delimiter instead of the more usual slash, to prevent confusion with the text to be substituted. The output is redirected to the new version of the file, instead of the standard output.

Comment: Many thanks. That was concise and correct. Is there a similar command to simply delete the comment slashes if they occur on a line with LogMsg()?

Comment: s? is the opposite of s^ I take it?

Comment: @musasabi No. The question mark is just a separator. The string beginning with s means: substitute the // with nothing. The ? identifies where the string to be replaced,and its replacement, begin and end. And yes, a better reverse is (forget the one above: sed 'LogMsg/  s?^//?^?' filename > new_filename. The hat ^ indicates the beginning of the line, the dollar sign $ indicates the line end.